# How to load two neural networks in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

Let's say I have two jupyter notebooks, one for each neural network. They both are for binary classification. I want to combine the results of two networks, for example I want the probability of x belonging to a class to be 0.2*model1(x)+0.8*model2(x).

I saved both models with

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'saved_networks/model1.pt')
```

Now I saw that in order to load a model I first have to create an object of this class

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

But I have these classes in two different notebooks, so my question is how does one usually handles such situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you write the two classes properly in `.py` files. This way you can import those classes anywhere you want (let it be a notebook or another python file). For instance, if you have `Model1` and `Model2` classes defined in `models.py` you can then import them, initialize separate models and load their respective state dictionaries:

```
from models import Model1, Model2

model1 = Model1(*args, **kwargs)
model2 = Model2(*args, **kwargs)

model1.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH1))
model2.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH2))
```